# How to recurse until unique MongoDB field value is created, and then insert new document with new value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, recursion, stormpath

I am trying to use a recursive function (below) to check if "bob" already is a user in my MongoDB, and if it is, to alter it slightly until it is unique, and then insert the document into my DB.

```
function changeName(x){
    MongoClient.connect(URI, function(err, db){
        db.collection('users').findOne({"user": x}, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            if (result && result.user == x){
                console.log("match found: " + result.user + " =  " + x + 
                "\n ...changing name...");
                //change name:
                x += Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
                changeName(x);
            }
            console.log("x = " + x);
            console.log("no match!");
            return x;
        });
    });
}
```

The above function does change the name if a match is found, i.e. `changeName("bob");` might change it to "bob7", but I need to run a callback function that takes the new name and then creates a new document with the new name as the username value.

Is there a way I can have the callback function but not in the recursion?

**Background information:**

I am using Stormpath for my site's user authentication and I have social logins set up for Google and Facebook. It works great, but I want to modify it slightly. With social login, the username for the account automatically becomes the email address associated with the account the user used to sign in.

In my app the username is public facing, so I don't want to show people's email addresses, but I like the immediate log-in that users experience with Stormpath social login.

So, in my Stormpath `postLogin` handler I am scrubbing out the @ symbol and anything that comes after it.

The problem, as you might have guessed, is that someone might try to register and they have "bob@gmail.com" as their Google account, but someone might have already registered on my site using the username "bob".

To give an idea of what I'm doing in the `postLogin` handler, this is pseudo-code:

```
if(document found with that name){
    if(document found with that name and that email){
        //this is an existing user account, loggin in..
    }else{
        //name already taken, changing name...
    }

}else{
    //no document found with that user name, creating a new user account...
}
```

Comment: Can't you just add an else for the `if (result && result.user == x){` that inserts the new record?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of recursion here? Second I think your create record method should be used in the postLogin handler under the first else statement below document found condition, so if you are in that condition, you can do change the name and have the new user name you want to create then below that have the db.collection.create method with the new username then return the new document. not sure if that would be an answer so i thought its better to comment

Comment: @jmona789 that worked - I also had defined my changeName() function outside the scope and it was causing some issues, but I moved the definition into the scope of the call and it was good to go. Thanks!

Comment: @Waheedi I have it working now, but thank you for your response. I am using recursion here because I need the function to alter the username and check the altered username against the DB until it is unique.

Comment: That makes sense then :) you are welcome Jake.